# App not available in Google Play Store from Samsung Galaxy Camera

Tags: android, camera, galaxy

I've published an app in the Google Play Store. The app is available on all android devices. Recently, I've discovered that the app is not visible in the Google Play store from the Samsung Galaxy Camera (JellyBean 4.1.1).

Do I need to set any special permission for the app to show up in Samsung Galaxy Camera?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check you have:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false">
```

As the Camera has no ability to make phone calls/sms.

Hopefully that will solve it, (Of course if you are using telephony features make sure you disable them via PackageManager).

Comment: If that doesn't solve it, please also provide the output from running the aapt dump badging commmand on your APK (in addition to the manifest).